# SQL Server query to get date and naming columns by years

Tags: sql-server

I want my query to get the years and add it without me to added manually each year such as my below query.

Note that each columns should be named as it's years

```
USE [My_Table]
GO
  
DECLARE @max_intyear INT = 0 , @max_byteQuarter INT = 0

SELECT @max_intyear = MAX(intyear), @max_byteQuarter = MAX(byteQuarter) 
FROM [My_Table].[dbo].[PW_Projected]

BEGIN
    SELECT     
        intMedicine, intForm,
        MAX(CASE WHEN intyear = @max_intyear  and byteQuarter = @max_byteQuarter   THEN curprice END) AS curprice,
        MAX(CASE WHEN byteQuarter = 1 AND intYear = 2016  THEN [curUnits] END) AS '2016_Units(ID) Q1' ,
        MAX(CASE WHEN byteQuarter = 2 AND intYear = 2016  THEN [curUnits] END) AS '2016_Units(ID) Q2',
        MAX(CASE WHEN byteQuarter = 3 AND intYear = 2016  THEN [curUnits] END) AS '2016_Units(ID) Q3',
        MAX(CASE WHEN byteQuarter = 4 AND intYear = 2016  THEN [curUnits] END) AS '2016_Units(ID) Q4',
        MAX(CASE WHEN byteQuarter = 1 AND intYear = 2017  THEN [curUnits] END) AS '2017_Units(ID) Q1' ,
        MAX(CASE WHEN byteQuarter = 2 AND intYear = 2017  THEN [curUnits] END) AS '2017_Units(ID) Q2',
        MAX(CASE WHEN byteQuarter = 3 AND intYear = 2017  THEN [curUnits] END) AS '2017_Units(ID) Q3',
        MAX(CASE WHEN byteQuarter = 4 AND intYear = 2017  THEN [curUnits] END) AS '2017_Units(ID) Q4'
    INTO
        Test 
    --intYear
    FROM         
        dbo.PW_Projected
    WHERE 
        intYear >= 2016
    GROUP BY 
        intMedicine, intForm
END
```

Comment: So in 10 years time you have 40 columns??

Answer (score 0):

You can generate dynamic sql, store it in a string variable (e.g. @SQL) and run it with sp_executesql @SQL.

Dynamic sql query could look like this (syntax errors could possibly occur, I didn't run it in SSMS):

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = N''
declare @YearQuarterSelection nvarchar(max) = N''

declare @YearQuarterTable table (
        y int  
      , q int
)

-- get all years and quarters
insert into @YearQuarterTable  (
   y 
 , q
)
select 
   y  = intYear 
 , q  = byteQuarter
from  dbo.PW_Projected
group by intYear, byteQuarter


-- generate "case when" conditions
select @YearQuarterSelection = N' MAX(CASE WHEN byteQuarter = ' + 
       cast (q as nvarchar(1)) + 
       N' AND intYear = ' +
       cast (y as nvarchar(4))
       N' THEN [curUnits] END) AS ''' + 
       cast (y as nvarchar(4)) + 
       N'_Units(ID) Q' +
       cast (q as nvarchar(1)) + 
       N''',' 
from YearQuarterSelection 

-- remove last comma
select @YearQuarterSelection = left(YearQuarterSelection, len(YearQuarterSelection) - 1)

-- build dynamic query
select @sql = N'SELECT intMedicine, intForm, MAX(CASE WHEN intyear = ' +  
               cast(@max_intyear as nvarchar(4)) + 
              N' and byteQuarter = ' + 
               cast(@max_byteQuarters nvarchar(1)) + 
              N' THEN curprice END) AS curprice, ' + 
               @YearQuarterSelection + 
              N'INTO
                 Test 
               --intYear
               FROM         
                 dbo.PW_Projected
               WHERE 
                 intYear >= 2016
               GROUP BY 
                 intMedicine, intForm' 

-- run dynamic query
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Best regards, Stephan